# slider tooltip extension without jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'd like to imitate what jquery mobile does [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/slider-tooltip/) but without loading the library. Just using jquery and jquery-ui (I'd probably stop using jquery-ui if I knew how to create sliders without it).

I want to show the slider value (ui.value) inside the slider handle (ui.handle) and also in a div above the handle, like in the third example (Both options together):

```
var initialValue = 5;

$("#slider").slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 50,
    value: initialValue,
    start: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.handle).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').show();
    },
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.handle).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').hide();
    },
    slide: function( event, ui) {
        $(ui.handle).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').text(ui.value);
        $(ui.handle).text(ui.value);
    },
    create: function( event, ui ) {
        var tooltip = $('<div class="ui-slider-tooltip" />').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: -25,
            left: 0,
            border: '1px grey'
        });

        $(event.target).find('.ui-slider-handle').append(tooltip);
        $('.ui-slider-handle').text(initialValue);
    }
    });
```

But for some unknown reason, manipulating the slider handle is preventing to append anything to it or show/hide it.

I'm also having trouble to set the border of the tooltip, when inspecting the code it adds none automatically, and I don't know why... (jquery-ui ofc but why?)

I just want something like jquery mobile.

http://jsfiddle.net/udxgkbmv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to try to do it with a fancy text-shadow, but that wasn't going to work. I was able to add another inner DIV and appended it after the tooltip DIV. By default both the tooltip DIV and the inner DIV would have the initialValue in it. The slide event now updates both the inner and tooltip DIVs.

The issue with the border not showing up was just missing the border type (e.g., solid). I didn't add any styling to the tooltip or inner, and will leave that up to you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var initialValue = 5;

     $("#slider").slider({
         min: 1,
         max: 50,
         value: initialValue,
         start: function( event, ui ) {
             $(ui.handle).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').show();
         },
         stop: function( event, ui ) {
             $(ui.handle).find('.ui-slider-tooltip').hide();
         },
         slide: function( event, ui) {
             $(ui.handle).find('div').text(ui.value);
             //$(ui.handle).text(ui.value);
         },
         create: function( event, ui ) {
              var tooltip = $('<div class="ui-slider-tooltip" />').css({
                 position: 'absolute',
                 top: -25,
                 left: 0,
                 border: '1px solid gray',
                 display: 'none'
             }).text(initialValue);
             var inner = $('<div class="ui-slider-inner" />').css({
                 position: 'absolute',
                 top: 0,
                 left: 0,
                 display: 'block'
             }).text(initialValue);
             $(event.target).find('.ui-slider-handle').append(tooltip).append(inner);
             //$('.ui-slider-handle').text(initialValue);
         }
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/udxgkbmv/3/

Comment: Thanks, I tried some css and it's working, but I cant make the inner div text align in the center: http://jsfiddle.net/udxgkbmv/4/

Comment: Also do you have any idea how to add a highlight to the left of the handle? Like the progress bar, I don't know the name of that...

Comment: Ok, forget the second question: just adding "range: 'min',".

Comment: Glad I could help. If you haven't figured it out already, you can get the inner DIV to align center by adding left:0, and right:0;. Since it's positioned absolute, it will stretch to it's container. This is a nice solution because it's not dependent on the container size: http://jsfiddle.net/udxgkbmv/5/